# Change href of wordpress menu item for specific page id

Tags: jquery, wordpress

i am a newbee and i searched all over but couldnt find a clue

i have a wordpress site what i want is to change its menu item href for specific pages how is it possible?
I am using the below jquery code but it isnt working

Regards tapos

Comment: yes i m creating it from dashboard

Comment: u didnt get my question what i want is if a user goes to a specific page the href of the menu item on that specific page gets change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
if($('.page-id').length === 1){
$('.page-id #menu-item > a').attr("href","Your desired href");    
}
```

Regards Khan